# Materialboxed does not work with data:image/png; base64

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

I am using materializecss v0.100.1, I have problems with the class 'materialboxed'. I am loading the images from an "input file multiple" to an Array of files, then I walk with the array a `$.each` and I add it to a div with the class 'collection'.

I can visualize the images but when I click on the image the 'materialboxed' class does not work. I have already initialized it with `$('.materialboxed').materialbox()` .I need to click on the thumbnail image to be displayed on the entire screen. Thank you.

```
$('#collection').empty();
$.each(files, function(k, v) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
      var algo = "<li class=\"collection-item avatar\"><img src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" alt=\"imagen\" class=\"circle\"/><span class=\"title truncate\">" + theFile.name + "</span><p>" + typeOfFile(theFile.type) + "<br/>" + (bytesToSize(theFile.size)) + "</p><a onclick=\"removeFile(" + theFile + ")\" class=\"secondary-content\"><i class=\"material-icons\">delete</i></a></li>";
      $('#collection').append(algo);
      $('#collection').find('img').addClass('materialboxed');
    };
  })(v);

  reader.readAsDataURL(v);

});
```

Comment: You say " I have already initialized it with $('.materialboxed').materialbox()". You mean that you did this at some point previous to the code in your sample, yes? If so, then I would guess you need to run `$('.materialboxed').materialbox()` again after your .each loop completes. Because when you ran it previously, these new elements you've just added did not exist, and therefore that command could not act on them - they didn't exist and so were not included in the group of elements selected by `$('.materialboxed')`.

Comment: I initialize it when the DOM is ready, after each loop as well. The course with the magnifying glass (icon) appears on the image, but when clicking, it is not displayed on the entire screen. If an image is loaded manually it works, but otherwise I have that problem. I hope I have explained myself properly, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Was struggling with this problem as well, the issue was that even if you call `$('.materialboxed').materialbox()` after `reader.readAsDataURL(v);` in the loop the image wasn't loaded in already. To force this to only run after the image has loaded I added the following after `reader.readAsDataURL(v);`

```
reader.onloadend = function () {
  $('.materialboxed').materialbox();
};
```